# Error after self-update NuGet Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nuget

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 to build and deploy a dotnet core application. Now I needed to update NuGet because some packages required a newer nuget version.

The version of NuGet, when installed from the repository (using sudo apt-get install nuget) is: 2.8.7.0

Then I used the self-update capability of nuget to update it: 'sudo uget update -self'. The output of this operation:

```
user@UbuntuFresh:~$ sudo nuget update -self
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 2.8.7.
Updating NuGet.exe to 3.5.0.
Update successful.
```

But when I now try to start nuget, I get this error:

```
user@UbuntuFresh:~$ nuget
Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
  Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
  Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
  Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.
```

Does anyone have any ideas, how to find out, what I'm missing? I can reproduce this (the build machine is a VirtualBox) and in another VM, the self-update was successful AND nuget still is working.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further poking around I stumbled over the solution. I additionally had to install the mono-complete package (which seemed to not be required until then).
The following command solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Comment: Thanks.  Solved my prob.

Comment: While this does solve the problem, I'm left wondering whether or not the nuget team knows about the issue?  It seems to me that `nuget update -self` should at least write out a warning, or better, an error, indicating that **mono** is required in order to run the latest version.